# Error of bisector method

Tags: astrophysics, spectroscopy

How to determine the error of bisector velocity span? I have found the article below, but I do not know what all quantities mean. What is the number of lines in the mask? How to find out x? How to determine the slope dF/dV? Should it be the slope of a linear fit of the profile between top_f and bot_f or top_i and bot_i? What if the slope is different on both sides of profile?

[image]
[image]

Source: [Martínez Fiorenzano et al. 2005](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2005A%26A...442..775M/abstract)